# Windows 7 installation problems

Tags: windows-7, installation

I have a problem while installing Windows 7 (and I had the same problem with Vista). The installation always gets stuck at "Expanding Windows Files".

I've tried changing graphics cards, memory, the hard disk and even the DVD-drive, but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Here's a thread where people solve the problem with an incredible variety of random solutions:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproinstall/thread/2aec8bd7-c05d-4de0-a31a-92458c8c3bf7

Comment: That step in the installation is very memory intensive, so it really sounds like a memory issue.  But you already stated that you swapped out the memory, so now I'm wondering if the memory you're using has the proper specs for that motherboard.  Also, is the system overclocked?  If so, reverting to default BIOS settings (as suggested by TomWij) should get rid of that, but you might want to confirm that any overclocking is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Does your motherboard need a Sata driver loaded at the beginning of setup?

At what percentage does it get stuck?

Is the installation DVD one that you burned? If so burn it at 4x or lower.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the BIOS, get another proper DVD and the last option is to replace the other hardware.